# Why does the 'setAttribute' function not work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, attributes

I am working on a django project and have a simple javascript inline code and want to disable a button and enable another one when some condition meets. I tried three method to do that but when condition meets and i expect to run code, no one work for me and nothing happend. 
here is this part of my code:

```
    {% else %}            
        <script >
            document.getElementById('prevBtn').removeAttribute('disabled');
            document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].disabled='disabled';
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        </script>
        <h2 >
             finished
             <h3>
              THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME <br>
               BYE!

             </h3>
        </h2>
    {% endif %}
<br>

<div><br>
    <button type="submit" id="nextBtn" name="nextBtn">next </button>
<br><br>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" name="prevBtn" disabled>previous</button>
</div>
```

Before i submit this question i read some similar questions and all suggest above approachs as answer. i'm confused what is wrong with my code.
thank in advance for any help.

EDIT:
For clarifying this is an django template document and full code is as below:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'RuleManager/style.css' %}">
{% block title_html %}
Expert Contract System
{% endblock %}
{% block h1 %}
Expert Contract
{% endblock %}
{% block article_content %}
<form id="expertform" method="post" action="{% url "ExpertSystem:expert_contract" %}" >
{% csrf_token %}

<h2>System message</h2>
<br>
<br>

<h3>{{ question }}</h3>
<br>
<br>

    {% if  question_type == 'Y/N'%}
        <select name="ynselect" >
             <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
             <option value="No">No</option>

        </select>
        <br>

    {% elif question_type == "EXP" %}

        <h3>Your answer</h3>
        <input name="answer" type="text">
        <br>
    {% else %}
        <script >
            document.getElementById('prevBtn').removeAttribute('disabled');
            document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].disabled='disabled';
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        </script>
        <h2 >
             finished
             <h3>
              THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME <br>
               BYE!
             </h3>
        </h2>
    {% endif %}
<br>

<div><br>
    <button type="submit" id="nextBtn" name="nextBtn">next </button>
<br><br>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" name="prevBtn" disabled>previous</button>
</div>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

its not work for you because the script is called before the html render to the DOM.
you need to move your script after the html tags

```
<div><br>
<button type="submit" id="nextBtn" name="nextBtn">next </button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" id="prevBtn" name="prevBtn" disabled>previous</button>
</div>
 <!-- THEN THE SCRIPT -->
<script >
        document.getElementById('prevBtn').removeAttribute('disabled');
        document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].disabled='disabled';
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    </script>
```

Comment: I edit the question and post full code and as you see this an django template html and when condition meets some message showed and then button must disable, thus i cant move the script after html tags. it must be just is {% else %} keyword block code.

Comment: so move the  html before your first if block

Comment: if i change document.getElementById('prevBtn').removeAttribute('disabled'); code for example with alert('something'), it run and work correctly. So it seems problem isn't where is script.

Comment: javascript is work before the html elemnts...
but javascript that need to do something with html lements need to came after them..
try alert ( document.getElementById('prevBtn') ) it will not find the html element...

Comment: yes already test it and not work. so do you can post complete modified code to check is it working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed  solution after a lot of search and tests, a simple way to get it done, and it is putting all scripts inside an external js file an using "defer" attribute like this:

```
<script  >
    var whythisdesc = '{{ whythisquestion }}';
    var howthisdesc = '{{ howthisanswer }}';
</script>
<script defer src="absolute address to javascript file" >
</script>
```

additionally i use global variable to access django template variables in external javascript file as described very good [here](http://www.filipyoo.com/accessing-django-template-variables-from-external-javascript-files/) .